# Python insert item in list maintaining order

Tags: python

I have a question about a list of tuples.

```
test = [('a', 1, 40), ('a', 2, 5), ('b', 2, 6), ('b', 3, 1)]
```

I basically want to add `('a', 3, 0)` and `('b', 2, 0)` to the list. preferably in the right order like this:

```
test = [('a', 1, 40), ('a', 2, 5), ('a',3 , 0), ('b' ,1 , 0) ('b', 2, 6), ('b', 3, 1)]
```

Does anyone have a nice and efficient idea how to do this? I am using python 3.5 right now. Please note that the actual problem is a bit more difficult so adding the points manually isn't a smart idea, because it can differ quite a bit.

Comment: What you mean by _right order_?

Comment: @Tunder250 You don't have a nested list, you have a list of tuples.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [bisect.insort](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) to insert any comparable element into a sorted list.

```
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.insort(test, ('a', 3, 0))
>>> bisect.insort(test, ('b', 2, 0))
>>> test
[('a', 1, 40), ('a', 2, 5), ('a', 3, 0), ('b', 2, 0), ('b', 2, 6), ('b', 3, 1)]
```